# JQuery Tablesorter Not Sorting Ajax Data

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I can get Tablesorter to work with static data, but not at all with Ajax data. I am using `jquery.tablesorter.js` (version 2.0.5b) with `jquery-1.7.2.min.js`. The browser is Firefox 27.0.1 running on Fedora. **Here is my code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Tags Table</h3>
<table id="tagsTable"> 
<thead>
<tr>
<th>tagname</th> 
<th>tagdesc</th>
<th>wtime</th>
</tr>
</thead> 
<tbody>
<tr><td>Empty Cell</td><td>Empty Cell</td><td>Empty Cell</td></tr>
</tbody> 
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#tagsTable").tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0],[1,0]]});

    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://localhost:8001/tags?uid=123",
          success: function(data) 
          { 
            $.each(data, function(key, value) 
            {   
                $.each(value, function(index, arVal) 
                {
                    $("tbody").append("<tr>");   
                    $("tbody").append("<td>" + arVal['tagname'] + "</td>");
                    $("tbody").append("<td>" + arVal['tagdesc'] + "</td>");
                    $("tbody").append("<td>" + arVal['wtime'] + "</td>");
                    $("tbody").append("</tr>"); 
                });
            });
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              console.log('error status = ' + status); 

              if(xhr.status==404)
              { 

              }  
          }
    });

    $("thead").click(function() {
        $("#tagsTable").tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0],[1,0]]});
        alert("thead has been clicked!");
    });

});  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The correct data is being pulled into the page.

When I click on a table header, the alert is activated, but no sorting occurs.

I have studied a few similar issues on SO, and some of those resolutions are still in my code. However, the problem has not been resolved.

Comment: I believe that is an issue with the original tablesorter (v2.0.5). Try out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which has lots of bug fixes and enhancements.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the newer version. Have also updated the code above to indicate its current state. The error mentioned is gone, but it still doesn't do much of anything. Any suggestions about what to try or study are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before your edit, the table "update" trigger was done properly, but now it is not included in the code above. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var $table = $("#tagsTable").tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0],[1,0]]}),
        $tbody = $table.children("tbody");

    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://localhost:8001/tags?uid=123",
          success: function(data)
          {
            $.each(data, function(key, value)
            {
                $.each(value, function(index, arVal)
                {
                    $tbody.append(
                        "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + arVal['tagname'] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + arVal['tagdesc'] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + arVal['wtime'] + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>"
                    );
                });
            });
            var resort = true,
                callback = function(){ console.log('table updated'); };
            $table.trigger("update", [ resort, callback ]);
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              console.log('error status = ' + status);

              if(xhr.status==404)
              {

              }
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do you get the "url: "http://localhost:8001/tags?uid=123"," value? Their documentation is a bit lacking.